# ThreadX module manager memory

Tags: threadx, azure-rtos

trying to build using IAR a sample of module and module_manager on STM32-H7 starting from the sample provided in "threadx-6.1.5_rel" and from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/rtos/threadx-modules/chapter3 i keep getting called the "module_fault_handler()" it seems because of memory error after calling txm_module_manager_start().

In the provided examples during module_manage initializations i see:

txm_module_manager_initialize((VOID *) 0x90000000, 0xE000);
txm_module_manager_external_memory_enable(&my_module, (void *) 0x90000000, 128, TXM_MODULE_MANAGER_SHARED_ATTRIBUTE_WRITE);

Is not clear to me from where the hard coded values comes and/or how they are calculated, seeing the file sample_threadx_module.icf i couldn't figure out this.
Thank you in advance

Comment: do you have external memory?

Answer (score 0):

The hardcoded values are just an example. Please provide memory locations that are compatible with your memory map.